# Design changes in library project of android studio does not affected

Tags: android, android-studio, opentok

I have integrated a text-chat-sample application in my project.

I want to change the design of the text-chat layout. For this I have to change the design in text-chat library. I have changed it but the  application is unaffected.

Are there any steps I need to follow in android studio?

Comment: It's not clear whether you are using a compiled library as dependency or a library module with the code. Can you explain how your project is structured? If you have the layout code, you can just change it. Otherwise you can extend some classes from the library and override their layouts. But without any further information there is no much more to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked it and tried to change the design in the library but it didn't take any changes which I have made.

So for solving this issue, I have copied all the required resources like Java class, XML files into my project.

Then I have made UI changes over there and it works perfectly.

Hope this will help you too ;)

Comment: @Rumin: bcz u r not here.